# How to avoid ES6 Javascript class inheritance naming collisions

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, es6-class

How does one avoid naming collisions from class inheritance in ES6 Javascript?

Large ES6 Javascript applications use a lot of inheritance, so much so that using generic names in a base class can mean debugging headaches later when creating derived classes. This can be a product of poor class design but seems more to be a problem with Javascript being able to scale up smoothly. Other languages provide mechanisms to hide inherited variables (Java) or properties (C#). Another way to alleviate this problem is to use private variables which isn't something Javascript has.

---

Here's an example of such a collision. A TreeObject class extends an Evented object (to inherit evented functionality) yet they both use `parent` to store their parent.

```
class Evented {
    constructor(parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
class TreeObject extends Evented{
    constructor(eventParent, treeParent) {
        super(eventParent);
        this.parent = treeParent;
    }
}
```

While this example is a bit artificial, I've had similar collisions in large libraries like Ember where terminology between the library and the end application overlap quite a bit causing me hours wasted here and there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really seems to be a design issue (use smaller objects and flatter hierarchies), but there's a solution to your problem as well: **symbols**!

```
const parentKey = Symbol("parent");
export class Evented {
    constructor(parent) {
        this[parentKey] = parent;
    }
}
```

```
import {Evented} from "…"
const parentKey = Symbol("parent");
class TreeObject extends Evented {
    constructor(eventParent, treeParent) {
        super(eventParent);
        this[parentKey] = treeParent;
    }
}
```

They will reliably prevent any collisions, as all symbols are unique, regardless of their descriptors.

Comment: The only *objective* answer available for this question.

Comment: I can even see this being a great emulation of private variables if the symbol in question is local to a file.

Comment: @Coburn not exactly, everyone can still enumerate the symbol-keyed properties of arbitrary objects, just like you can with the string-keys ones. It's only a matter of changing `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`.

Comment: @Bergi Dang, still a neat feature.

Answer (score 2):

> Large ES6 JavaScript applications use a lot of inheritance.

Actually, most of them don't. In a framework like Angular, one level of inheritance from the platform-defined classes is most common. Deep inheritance structures are brittle and best avoided. A large app might have some cases of two user levels of classes, A > B, where A contains a bunch of common logic and B1 and B2 are light specializations, such as a different template for a component, at a level that does not give rise to concerns about collisions.

Your example of `Evented` is semantically not really a parent class; it's more in the nature of a mixin. Since JS doesn't really handle mixins well, instead of deriving `Tree` from `Evented`, I'd hold the evented object as a property:

```
class TreeObject {
    constructor(eventParent, treeParent) {
        this.evented = new Evented(eventParent);
        this.parent = treeParent;
    }
    send(msg) { this.evented.send(msg); }
}
```

If you really want to design `Evented` for use as a mixin-like superclass, then it's the responsibility of the designer to make member variables as unique as possible, as in

```
export class Evented {
    constructor(parent) {
        this.eventedParent = parent;
    }
}
```

or use a symbol, as proposed in another answer. Or, consider using a map:

```
const parents = new Map();

class Evented {
  constructor(parent) {
    parents.set(this, parent);
  }
  sendParent(msg) {
    parents.get(this).send(msg);
  }
}
```

> I've had similar collisions in large libraries like Ember

I haven't. Ember classes typically define few members, and the methods they define are well-defined and well-known.

Of course, the real solution is to use a typing system such as TypeScript. It does provide private members/methods. If a method does need to be public, TS will not let you define a method by the same name on the subclass unless the signatures match.

Comment: On the Ember collisions, my most recent collision with Ember was having a `renderer` property on a component (to hold a WebGL renderer) that ended up colliding with some internal Ember property (I think it's private bc I don't see it in the docs). I had a similar problem with `send` and `sendAction` but both those are well documented. Twice is too much for me.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of minimizing this, that I can think of right the top of my head, is wrapping the internal state of your object, for your example that would be:

```
class Evented {
    constructor(parent) {
        this.eventedState = {
           parent : parent
        }

    }
}
```

And apply the same pattern to all the classes. Obviously this still means that you have one property per object that might collide, but it reduces the chance of collision. The downside of this is that its not perfect and refactoring your code to use this pattern might be quite painful.